# Rally Lookback API filter on Ready and Recycled

Tags: api, rally, lookbackapi

I am trying to use the lookback api to get stories that have the Ready flag set to true.  I appear to be able to output the ready flag but not filter on it.

I do not appear to be able to filter or output the recycled flag.

Curious if these fields are not available to the lookback api as filters.

Answer (score 3):

Nick is right about the Recycled artifacts.  I'm wondering though if you are quoting the Ready values and treating them like a String.  This field is actually a Boolean and can be queried like this:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/v2.0/service/rally/workspace/12352608129/artifact/snapshot/query.js?find={"Ready":true}&fields=true
```

This doesn't work (since it's matching on the string "true" instead of the Boolean true).

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/v2.0/service/rally/workspace/12352608129/artifact/snapshot/query.js?find={"Ready":"true"}&fields=true
```

It's also listed as #1 in the Tips and Tricks section of the documentation:
https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/doc/Analytics2.0LookbackAPIUserManual.html#h.ce80nb6raonb

Comment: thank you for the tip about treating Boolean as Booleans, and not strings.

Comment: thank you both for the info and references.  The Ready query is working, and the Recycled I can live without.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're correct. In [LBAPI documentation](https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/doc) examples that illustrate the  temporal data model show a gap when artifacts were moved to a recycle bin and later restored, or display no data after artifacts were moved to recycle bin and never restored.

Per [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14843249/lookback-api-deleted-items/14856659#14856659), Lookback API doesn't provide anything along the lines of tracking entries in the Recycle Bin.

As far as Ready flag, a query like this will return the field value:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/v2.0/service/rally/workspace/12352608129/artifact/snapshot/query.js?find={"ObjectID":{$in:[16483705391,14167827399]}}&fields=["Name","Ready"]
```

e.g.

```
{
Name: "my story",
Ready: false
},
{
Name: "my story",
Ready: true
},
```

and this query will return results if value `true` is treated as Boolean, not string, as SRMelody pointed out:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/v2.0/service/rally/workspace/12352608129/artifact/snapshot/query.js?find={"Ready":true}&fields=true
```