# Rally release scope change app tagging deleted items

Tags: rally

In the SDK 2.0 version of the Rally release scope change app, there is a filter being applied to search items that are in the recycle bin (in the _getSnapsForSubset function):

```
    var deleted_item_from_release_change_filter = Ext.create('Rally.data.lookback.QueryFilter', {
        property: 'Release',
        operator: 'in',
        value:release_oids
    }).and(Ext.create('Rally.data.lookback.QueryFilter', {
        property: '_PreviousValues.Recycled',
        value:false
    }));
```

In the returned result sets during processing I want to pull these out explicitly but I can't see an easy way to identify them.

During the filter process can I tag these records in some way so I can easily identify them later?

Answer (score 0):

You are using Snapshot store that gets data from LookbackAPI. Per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21740230/rally-lookback-api-filter-on-ready-and-recycled/21743060#21743060) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14843249/lookback-api-deleted-items/14856659#14856659) LBAPI doesn't track entries in the Recycle Bin, and there is no way to know when something has been restored from the recycle bin.
There is Recycled attribute on HierarchicalRequirement in WS API, but it reflects the current value (if the item is currently in the recycle bin, true or false), since WS API does not provide historical data.